# Laravel password reset email send /password/reset?{{token}} not /password/reset/{{token}}

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-5.7

I'm make my own website , i didn't use make:auth so i made it manually , i just made default password reset routes , everything work smoothly but when user request password reset email .. link is like that : 
 http://localhost/password/reset?1db6371731551e7ceec18d6ffbeed6749478bb3edf746bb0269c09e78bd8e525
so it use

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
```

**Not**

```
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');<br>
```

.. how can i fix it ?

[image: password reset email]

Comment: Can you show us your method who send the mail, and your method who receipt the user request. 

I want to show your url generation.

Comment: yea i can ... but i think no point as i didn't change the default ! , just putting routes and views @Saromase

Answer (score 0):

To have the result you want, I use that method, I dont know if that's the best, but it work.

```
$token = '1db6371731551e7ceec18d6ffbeed6749478bb3edf746bb0269c09e78bd8e525';
$URL = action('Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm').'/'.$token;
```

It's generate URL like what you want.